# How do I get I-filter to define a category for my page?

Tags: url, filter

I am making a webpage for managing students grades, essays, tests etc.
The school however is using something called I-filter and it is blocking my site because it says 'URL category unknown'.

Does anyone know how to make filters that define a category for your site?

This is the url for my site: https://ymcawakayama.pythonanywhere.com/

I am using pythonanywhere to host it. However, I am not sure if that has any effect.

I am not really sure what I need to try to do to fix it. Anyone who's got any idea?